# What would make ALL my browsers refuse to stay logged in sites?

Tags: windows-8.1, browser

Basically, I can't stay logged in anymore in multiple different websites, this affects Internet Explorer (dunno what one, came with this Win 8), Chrome (current stable) and Palemoon (current stable).

The symptoms range from the occasional logging off, to logging off right after logging in (example: chucklefish forums, it logs in, but as soon I try to do something it is logged off again), to infinite redirect loops, to not being able to login at all (example: trying to logging in Deviant Art just reloads the webpage, without actually logging in).

This also affect some other sites "sessions" not necessarily related to logins, for example when visiting Microcenter site it keeps asking what location I want to see, sometimes it stays put, but after clicking 2 or 3 hyperlinks, it loses the setting again, also it keeps wiping out the shopping cart randomly.

I tried removing some software (like malwarebytes anti-exploit), wiping out all cookies, enable all cookies, enable uBlock Origin, disable it again, and so on...

I dunno what to look for now, since I am not a web-dev and I dunno how sites store sessions, beside cookies (using a cookie-reading plug-in they seemly look fine).

Comment: Did you get a new internet provider? Or did your provider change something? It could be caused by Carrier-grade NAT. So your public IP changes a lot and the sites don't recognize you anymore.

Comment: Do you have an internet security suite such as Norton, McAfee or Kaspersky? Many of these have cookie blocker modules that might cause this type of thing...

Comment: I had the same problem a couple of months ago. It turned out to be Norton Internet Security. I uninstalled it.

Comment: I have iobit systemcare and malwarebytes stuff

Comment: TJJ that is good to know too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is a Man in the Middle attack.

I don't fully fixed it, but the basics:

Somewhere in my network (I didn't found out yet), some routers are using DNS servers that are NOT the ones I setup.

Also, many machines, of many different OSes (I saw affected: Windows 8.1, OSX El Capitan, Ubuntu, Fedora) got their DNS settings changed explicitly.

The rogue DNS then cause bugs when you are trying to login on websites, because it is attempting to steal login credentials.

I realized what was going on, when the attack partially succeeded: I was trying to access my online banking, and noticed it was asking unusual information, for example it was asking my ATM password, that is not used on web banking.

After changing the DNS back on the machines, the bank true page "returned", and random logoff mostly stopped... Some router somewhere is still problematic though, but now my network is mostly useable again.